# how to regain the original font properties and its associated properties like bold, italics using python-docx while text replacement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using python-docx for a automation tool. I have a issue like once after I run the code for replacement of certain words in one list with corresponding in another list it is removing all the properties (like font size, font name, part of a text in bold or italics, bookmarks in the paragraphs or table) of the text in the paragraph and table and its coming with a plain text in "Calibri" with a font size of '12'.

The code that I used is:

```
wrongWord = "xyz"
correctWord = "abcd"
def iter_block_items(parent):
    if isinstance(parent, _Document):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")

    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)



document = Document(r"F:\python\documentSample.docx")
for block in iter_block_items(document):
    if isinstance(block, Paragraph):
        if wrongWord in block.text:
            block.text = block.text.replace(wrongWord, correctWord)
    else:
        for row in block.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                if wrongWord in cell.text:
                    cell.text = cell.text.replace(wrongWord, correctWord)

document.save(r"F:\python\documentSampleAfterChanges.docx")
```

Could you help me to get the same font size, font name and other associated properties to be copied from the original file after the text replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Search and replace is a hard problem in the general case, which is the main reason that feature hasn't been added yet.

What's happening here is that assigning to the `.text` attribute on the cell is removing all the existing runs and the font-related attributes are removed with those runs.

Font information (e.g. bold, italic, typeface, size) is stored at the *run* level (a paragraph is composed of zero or more runs). Assigning to the `.text` attribute removes all the runs and replaces them with a single *new* run containing the assigned text.

So the challenge is to find the text within the multiple runs somewhere, and preserve as much of the font formatting settings as possible.

This is a hard problem because Word breaks paragraph text into separate runs for many reasons, and runs tend to proliferate. There's no guarantee at all that your search term will be completely enclosed in a single run or start at a run boundary. So perhaps you start to see the challenge of a general-case solution.

One thing you can do that might work in your case is something like this:

```
# ---replace text of first run with new cell value---
runs = table_cell.paragraphs[0].runs
runs[0].text = replacement_text
# ---delete all remaining runs---
for run in runs[1:]:
    r = run._element
    r.getparent().remove(r)
```

Basically this replaces the text of the first run and deletes any remaining runs. Since the first run often contains the formatting you want, this can often work. If the first word is formatted differently though, say bold, then all the replacement text will be bold too. You'll have to see how this approach works in your specific case.

Comment: Thank you so much scanny. But I am getting an error as below
AttributeError: '_Cell' object has no attribute 'text_frame'
as well as I searched in the link below:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Cell

Comment: Oops, apologies, I gave you the code for `python-pptx`, not `python-docx` :) I've updated the code in the answer. Basically you just remove the `.text_frame` element and access paragraphs directly from the cell object.

Comment: The above code is not working when it come to a some text as follows
Sample paragraph:
**This paragraph starts as a bold text**. _After that sentence it goes as italic text_. Later it become normal text. **In this same paragraph it again become bold text. **
In the above sample paragraph after some text replacement the whole text turns out to be in bold and with the font that is given in the beginning of the text by using "run[0]"  but my requirement is to regain the original format that is given in the upcoming lines.

Comment: @vikashvishnu this is exactly the hard problem I was describing. You would have to map the starts and lengths of each run, figure out which run and offset within the run your search term started and ended in, and then manipulate those runs to replace your text.